# Incremental Imaging of running systems

Tags: image, acronis

Windows environment: I have a need of guaranteeing a prompt recovery for a number of running physical clients. There is a FDI taken with Acronis B&R  11.5 solution, which I can transform to a VM. As the time passes, there is a distinct possibility the recovered VMs will be out of the domain because of the Access token age. The solution should guarantee the recovery doesn't involve the re-joining the client to the domain.
Till now my best guess would be: take a bi-monthly incremental image of the machine, then create a VM from the latest image. I could not find references of an incremental image with Acronis in the docs.
Do you think it is possible to implement the above? Any suggestions?

Comment: I'll clarify the initial request: be able to recover a physical machine to a virtual machine instance, which should have a full active directory domain functionality.
(this functionality cannot be guaranteed when a Full disk image becomes too old and the AD token expires, so an additional intervention is required to put the machine back into the domain).

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting it (Acronis 11.5, Windows environment) I can confirm. It is a commercial solution as mentioned in the question but it has the functionality required: Acronis Backup 11.5 is able to take a Full disk image out of a running Windows client and has the possibility to restore the same onto it, from its management console.
So scheduling a Full disk image twice a month, you should be quite sure that you can restore a given Windows physical client to a VM that has a full AD domain functionality. More info can be found here: http://www.acronis.com/en-eu/support/documentation/ABR11.5/index.html